# Lit-Element | Property defined with @property doesn't trigger render

Tags: reactjs, polymer, lit-element

Example in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-uohq1?file=/src/index.tsx)
Property defined in the constructor trigger render but with decorator not.